# Convert cURL to Guzzle POST

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm adapting an example for upload an image to imgur. The example uses curl and I'm using guzzle ^6.1. The example with curl is:

```
<html>
  <h3>Form</h3>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000" />
    Image (< 50kb): <input type="file" name="upload" /><br/>
    ClientID: <input type="text" name="clientid" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload to Imgur" />
  </form>
</html>
<?php

if (empty($_POST['clientid']) || @$_FILES['upload']['error'] !== 0 || @$_FILES['upload']['size'] > 50000) {
    exit;
}

$client_id = $_POST['clientid'];

$filetype = explode('/',mime_content_type($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
if ($filetype[0] !== 'image') {
    die('Invalid image type');
}

$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => base64_encode($image) ));

$reply = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);

echo "<h3>Image</h3>";
printf('<img height="180" src="%s" >', @$reply->data->link);

echo "<h3>API Debug</h3><pre>";
var_dump($reply);
```

I'm try to convert to Guzzle using the next code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as gRequest;   
//....Clases and functions ...

        $url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json";
        $client_id = "miclientid";            
        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => $url,
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'timeout'  => 15.0,
        ]);    
        $gRequest  = new gRequest('POST', 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json', [
                        'headers' => [
                            'Authorization: Client-ID' => $client_id
                        ],
                        'image' => "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..."

        ]);

        $gResponse = $client->send($gRequest, ['timeout' => 2]);
```

But I receive a 400 bad request; What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On first glance, I see two issues:

1. The `Authorization` header. In your Guzzle version, you use `Authorization: Client-ID` as **header name** and `$client_id` as header value. This will generate a (wrong) HTTP header that looks like this:

   ```
   Authorization: Client-ID: myclientid
   ```

   **Solution:** Pass your headers like this:

   ```
   "headers" => [
       "authorization" => "Client-ID " . $clientId
   ]
   ```
2. The request body. Your original, cURL-based version contained a URL query-encoded body with an `image` parameter. That parameter contained the base64 encoded raw contents of the image file. In your Guzzle version, you **actually do not send a body at all**, as you're using the non-existent `image` option (have a look at the [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html) for a list of all supported options). Also, your original example did not contain the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix (which is usually just a hint for the browser).

   Try passing the parameters as follows:

   ```
   "form_params" => [
       "image" => base64_encode(/* image content here */)
   ]
   ```